# Integrate the function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Find the following integral,

$$I_n=\displaystyle\int (\arctan \theta)^n\ d\theta$$

Thinking that maybe there is some reduction formula, I tried using integration by parts but unable to derive it. Any help will be appreciated.

Actually the problem that I have been struggling over for quite some time is of finding $I_2$. If it can be solved, that will also be of great help.

Comment: Do you have any limits for the integral? (i.e., is the integral part of some definite integral?)

Comment: Wolfram says "no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions", so I wish you the best of luck :)

Comment: @Adhvaitha: No.

Comment: @Adhvaitha How did you stumble across this integral anyways? Even the antiderivative of $(\arctan(\theta))^2$ is extremely nasty to obtain.

Comment: @GDumphart: Can you tell me the method of obtaining the antiderivative of $(\arctan \theta)^2$ and the result? I hope to get some clue from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic method for obtaining $\mathcal{I}_{1}$ is integration by parts:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}_{1}
&=\int\arctan{(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=x\arctan{(x)}-\int\frac{x}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=x\arctan{(x)}-\frac12\ln{\left(x^2+1\right)}+\color{grey}{constant}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

The strategy for obtaining $\mathcal{I}_{2}$ is similar, except this time we have to integrate by parts twice. Then, an explicit formula for the anti-derivative may be obtained in terms of a non-elementary special function known as the [Clausen function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function):

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}_{2}
&=\int\arctan^2{(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=x\arctan^2{(x)}-\frac12\ln{\left(x^2+1\right)}\arctan{(x)}-\int\frac{x\arctan{(x)}-\frac12\ln{\left(x^2+1\right)}}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=x\arctan^2{(x)}-\frac12\ln{\left(x^2+1\right)}\arctan{(x)}-\int\frac{x\arctan{(x)}}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~ +\frac12\int\frac{\ln{\left(x^2+1\right)}}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=x\arctan^2{(x)}-\frac12\ln{\left(x^2+1\right)}\arctan{(x)}-\frac12\ln{\left(x^2+1\right)}\arctan{(x)}\\
&~~~~~ +\frac12\int\frac{\ln{\left(x^2+1\right)}}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac12\int\frac{\ln{\left(x^2+1\right)}}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=x\arctan^2{(x)}-\ln{\left(x^2+1\right)}\arctan{(x)}+\int\frac{\ln{\left(x^2+1\right)}}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=x\arctan^2{(x)}-\ln{\left(x^2+1\right)}\arctan{(x)}+\int\ln{\left(\sec^2{\theta}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta;~~x=\tan{\theta}\\
&=x\arctan^2{(x)}-\ln{\left(x^2+1\right)}\arctan{(x)}-2\int\ln{\left(\cos{\theta}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=x\arctan^2{(x)}-\ln{\left(x^2+1\right)}\arctan{(x)}+2\ln{(2)}\,\theta-\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\pi-2\theta\right)}+\color{grey}{constant}\\
&=x\arctan^2{(x)}-\ln{\left(x^2+1\right)}\arctan{(x)}+2\ln{(2)}\arctan{(x)}-\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\pi-2\arctan{(x)}\right)}+\color{grey}{constant}.\\
\end{align}$$